# How to make a script run in buildroot as a boot script after init

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, buildroot

I am building a custom initramfs from buildroot with busybox to be used for automated fdisk partitioning. How/where to put a script file so that busybox boots and executes it automatically.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, are you really asking two questions? (1) How to get a script to execute on the target when or after it boots.  (2) How to get Buildroot to install this script into the root filesystem.  You really haven't provided enough details to answer either definitively, although guesses could be made that would essentially work.

Comment: I am asking the second one. I can do it as part of init script for the first part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to make a script run in buildroot as a boot script after init

You cannot use one script file for both purposes.  You'll need one script for execution on the target, and a method on the host to modify the target's prototype filesystem.

The typical method of installing scripts and files into the target's filesystem generated by Buildroot is to specify a "post-build script".  This script is executed before the root filesystem is `tar`ed or `ubinize`d.

From section *4.1 Customizing the generated target filesystem* of the [Buildroot user manual](http://free-electrons.com/~thomas/br-manual.pdf):

> In the Buildroot configuration, you can specify the path to a post-build script, that gets called *after* Buildroot builds all the selected software, but
>   *before* the rootfs packages are assembled.  The destination root filesystem folder is given as the first argument to this script, and this script can then be used to copy programs, static data or any other needed file to your target filesystem.

A subdirectory for your board under the Buildroot **board** directory (e.g. **board/beaglebone**) is a typical location to store the post-build.sh file as well as the original files for copying.

An example of a post-build.sh file is [here](https://github.com/linux4sam/buildroot-at91/blob/buildroot-2013.02-at91/board/atmel/sama5d3ek_demo/post-build.sh).  Two script files for the target are created line-by-line using `echo` commands.  A binary file is simply copied.

Also take a look at pages 24-25 of [this presentation](http://elinux.org/images/2/2a/Using-buildroot-real-project.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am guessing that my cp commands in the script do the trick while building the rootfs. I still feel that its not a clean way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't as clean, but putting files into a folder and using the overlay settings can work pretty well. Naturally this folder is just raw copied into the target file system, but for simple scripts it is a good option.